# Meteor helper erroring

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm defining a simple helper:

```
ccFees: function(){
  var event = Events.findOne(this._id);
  return event
}
```

Which returns the object: [object Object]

But when I add a property, which exists, of the that object like so:

```
ccFees: function(){
  var event = Events.findOne(this._id);
  return event.cost
}
```

...it errors.

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined
```

Oddly enough, the info appears as intended on the first render, but if I modify the object for example after that initial creation, then it errors. Any help would be appreciated. This is a super routine task but it's bombing. Is this possibly Blaze related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property does exist, but not the object. Database calls on the client side returns only what's already fetched via the subscription channel, so before your object is pulled from the server the `findOne` method can return null. I'm not sure why in your case this happens after the update, but that's the general idea.

The fix is simple: add a safeguard to check whether the object you're working on exists:

```
ccFees: function() {
  var event = Events.findOne(this._id);
  if(!event) return '';
  return event.cost;
},
```

In that simple case you can write it in the short form:

```
ccFees: function() {
  var event = Events.findOne(this._id);
  return event && event.cost;
},
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand. If we're requesting the document from the db, and assigning it to a variable and returning that variable, and literally on the page you see [object Object] and when we console log the returned variable we can inspect the object and see "cost" sitting there ready to be called, why would scoping to that property cause an error? This seems like a routine task. Thank you for your response, just trying to understand.